# Call parameter through a webapp?

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, web-applications

The code below gets the distance between 2 different addresses and returns the distance in miles, kilometers or minutes.  My understanding was that I could execute my app-script in a web app using google.script.run.googleMaps();

My question is how do I use input fields as my from and two columns to replicate the same result in a web app?

```
function googleMaps(start_address,end_address, return_type){

   var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
   mapObj.setOrigin(start_address);
   mapObj.setDestination(end_address);
   var directions = mapObj.getDirections();

   var getTheLeg = directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0];

   var meters = getTheLeg["distance"]["value"];

  switch(return_type){
    case "miles" :
      return Math.floor(meters * 0.000621371);
      break;
    case "kilometers" :
      return meters / 1000;
      break;
    case "minutes" :
      var duration = getTheLeg["duration"]["value"];
      return duration / 60;
      break;
    default :
      return "Error: Wrong unit type";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Passing parameters to a WebApp

- A WebApp must contian a [`function doGet(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#requirements_for_web_apps) (or alternatively `doPost(e)`), which will be the first function to be run when the WebApp is called
- When you deploy a WebApp, the WebApp URL will be something like this:
  `https://script.google.com/a/XXXXX.eu/macros/s/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/exec`
- If you want to pass paramters to the url, you should do it like
  `https://script.google.com/a/XXXXX.eu/macros/s/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/exec?start_address=AAA&end_address=BBB&return_type=CCC`
- Those parameters can be retrieved within the WebApp as

```
function doGet(e){
 var start_address = e.parameter.start_address;
 var end_address = e.parameter.end_address;
 var return_type = e.parameter.return_type;
 ...
}
```

- Now, you can completely integrate your function within `doGet()` - you do not need `google.script.run.googleMaps();` for it

---

- If you do want to call your function with [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run), note that it is a method that calls an Apps Script function from within client-side (Javascript)
- If you want to use it, it means that first you need to create a client-side with [`HtmlService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service)
- Second, you will need to pass the retrieved parameters from Apps Script to Javascript and back

Answer (score 1):

You can pass them directly:
`google.script.run.googleMaps(start_address,end_address, return_type);`