# Google web app - Generate another html from default html file and carry value from default html to new html

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I need to ask the user to select a value and after that I want to generate a new html page which will display the selected value.

Step1: the app generates a list of values and the user need to pick a value (I know how to do it and I used a simplified version for this test)

Step2: Once the user click the value, a new html file is generated and the selected value will appear as a text (I do not know how to do this)

The default html file is the following (f.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="text-align: center;">Test - Step 1</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>

<p style="text-align: center;"><select id="sel1" style="width: 230px; height: 35px; margin: 0px 0 0px 0;">
<option selected="selected" value="">email</option>
</select></p>

<script>

function listS() {
  const selectElem = document.getElementById('sel1');
    const index = selectElem.selectedIndex;
  if (index > -1) {
    const e = document.getElementById("sel1");
    const value = e.options[index].value;
    const body = { index: index, value: value };
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(yourCallBack).yourServerSideFunc(body);
  }  
}



document.getElementById("sel1").addEventListener("click",listS);

function yourCallBack() {

}
</script>


  </body>
</html>
```

The js file is:

```
function doGet() {

  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('f');
  return output;

}

function yourServerSideFunc(body) {
  var value = body["value"];
 var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('f2');
  return output;
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({message: "ok"})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

The new html file (f2) is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="test"style="text-align: center;">Your value is</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Once I am able to generate the new html, I need to change the text to: "Your value is: "+value. However I cannot even generate the f2.html. How can I do that?

Comment: You don't necessary have to create a whole new page.  You could just use  a message div that is currently not visible and use it.

Comment: I will give it a try as I am not familiar on how to show/hide HTML content. Specially because I need to "substitute" the drop down list with another text. However, is there a way to generate another html file as described above? Is that supported by google script?

Comment: in JQuery it's $('#id").css('display', 'block');

Comment: Here's some other examples in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205148/changing-visibility-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

- You  needs a *value*, otherwise value is empty.
- Your `yourServerSideFunc(body)` has two return values, obviously the second one is not being executed.
- If you want to redirect the user to a different page, do it by redirecting. But if you want to update content in the *base html* then you can use the style attribute of HTML element to hide or show elements.
- **You can also implement some conditionals into your `doGet(e)` and render a different content depending on a parameter or set thereof. This will yield a different HTML at the same URL.**

### For example:

1- User visits your web app, so `doGet()` is executed.

2- User selects an option from the dropdown, so browser listens for click event and executes `listS()`.

3- `listS()` passes the user selected value to `yourServerSideFunc` which returns HTML content to the callback `showDiv`.

4- `showDiv` is executed and the HTML content is updated.

---

#### Code.gs

```js
function doGet() {
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('f');
  return output;
}

function yourServerSideFunc(body) {
  console.log(body);
  var value = body["value"];
  var output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('f2');
  output.value = value;
  return output.evaluate().getContent();
}
```

---

#### f.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
    <p style="text-align: center;">Test - Step 1</p>
    <p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
    <select id="sel1" style="width: 230px; height: 35px; margin: 0px 0 0px 0;">
        <option selected="selected" value="email">email</option>
    </select>
    <div id="resultDiv" style="display: None;"></div>
    <script>
function listS() {
    const selectElem = document.getElementById('sel1');
    const index = selectElem.selectedIndex;
    if (index > -1) {
        const e = document.getElementById("sel1");
        const value = e.options[index].value;
        const body = {
            index: index,
            value: value
        };
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showDiv).yourServerSideFunc(body);
    }
}

function showDiv(value) {
    var resultDiv = document.getElementById("resultDiv");
    resultDiv.innerHTML = value;
    resultDiv.style.display = "Block";
}
document.getElementById("sel1").addEventListener("click", listS);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

#### f2.html

```html
<p id="test"style="text-align: center;">Your value is</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><?= value ?></p>
```

---

### Further reading:

[Apps Script Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#code.gs_6)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I still have the issue that the second html is generated below the first html in the same page, while I wanted to substitute them as they were 2 different pages. I think I will figure it out

Comment: Do you want to render an **new** html file in the same exact URL?

Comment: yes, I am using the work around as indicated above, but would still be nice to know how to render a new HTML in same URL if it is possible

Comment: It is as simple as implementing an `if(condition)` in your `doGet(e)`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61324847/4243927) for hints.  And you could also alternatively implement a `doPost(e)` and put some logic in it. If this render this, else render that.

Comment: interesting, that may also help me to solve another issue I have: call a web app from another web app. I will take a look, thanks!

Comment: Great! Please [accept/upvote the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if works for you.